# How to move column values from one column to another based on the data_time value on time-series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, modeling

I have a df

| Date_time | Universe_Location_1 | Universe_Location_2 | Universe_Location_3 | Universe_Location_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20.06.2023 11:00 | Saturn |  | mars | earth |

Considering
(i) Saturn moves from one location to another every 30 minutes
(ii) Mars moves from one location to another every 45  minutes
(iii) Earth Moves from one location to another every 60 minutes

Want to get the result_df on input of required time

example input 1 ------> 20.06.2023 11:30

result_df

| Date_time | Universe_Location_1 | Universe_Location_2 | Universe_Location_3 | Universe_Location_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20.06.2023 11:30 |  | Saturn | mars | earth |

example input 2 ----> 20.06.2023 11:45

result_df

| Date_time | Universe_Location_1 | Universe_Location_2 | Universe_Location_3 | Universe_Location_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20.06.2023 11:45 |  | Saturn |  | mars earth |

example input 3 ----> 20.06.2023 12:00

result_df

| Date_time | Universe_Location_1 | Universe_Location_2 | Universe_Location_3 | Universe_Location_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20.06.2023 12:00 | Earth |  | Saturn | mars |

Request to give me suggestions on how to solve this.

Comment: The question is very confusing, Location is in 3D space, i.e., X, Y and Z (x, y, z) and z is very different for all the planets and as earth moves the z is variable in itself that's why you have seasons. What is that you are looking for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can model the locations of each planet as a lambda function using the time difference and modulo:

```py
import pandas as pd

# read timestamp from string with pandas
start_time_string = "20.06.2023 11:00"
start_time = pd.to_datetime(start_time_string, format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")

# create a lambda function for each planet
saturn_location = lambda time : int(((time - start_time).total_seconds() / (30 * 60)) % 4)
mars_location = lambda time : int((((time - start_time).total_seconds() / (45 * 60)) + 2) % 4)
earth_location = lambda time : int((((time - start_time).total_seconds() / (60 * 60)) + 3) % 4)

# validate
print(saturn_location(start_time)) # 0
print(mars_location(start_time)) # 2
print(earth_location(start_time)) # 3
```

The 30, 45 and 60 in each lambda represent the number of minutes it takes the planet to go to the next location. The +2 / +3 models the initial starting position of the planets.

Note that the indexes of the planets location are zero-based. if you want to use your notation, simply add 1 each time.